# How do I get my images to fade-in in a gallery using pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

My images are changing but the fade-in effect is not being applied. How do I get it to work? Should I be setting the opacity outside the changeImage() function?

JavaScript beginner here.

```
  SCRIPT:
  var imageArray = ["IMG1.jpg","IMG2.jpg",
                 "IMG3.jpg","IMG4.jpg"];                        
   var imageIndex = 0;      
   var done = true;     
  var fading_image = document.getElementById("currentImg");

 //To fade image
  function function_opacity(opacity_value, fade_in_or_fade_out){
    fading_image.style.opacity = opacity_value / 100;
    fading_image.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity_value + ')';

    if (fade_in_or_fade_out == 'in' && opacity_value == 1) {
    fading_image.style.display = 'block';
    }

    if (fade_in_or_fade_out == 'in' && opacity_value == 100) {
    done = true;
    }
}

//To change image
function changeImage(){ 

    document.getElementById("currentImg").src = imageArray[imageIndex];
    imageIndex++;
    if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length){
        imageIndex = 0;
    }

    //Setting opacity
    if (done && fading_image.style.opacity != '1') {
    done = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        setTimeout("function_opacity(" + i + ",'in')", i * 5);
        }
    }
};
setInterval(changeImage, 2000);



HTML
<img src="IMG1.jpg" id="currentImg" alt="Gallery Image">
```

Comment: For your timeout you actually have to define a function or use the function you defined before and _not_ put it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons this issue may be occurring.

1) You probably need to use an anonymous function with setTimeout that contains the call to function_opacity, as the function takes parameters. setTimeout is expecting a function declaration, not an invocation.

2) Your i value may not be what you think it is. i contains a pointer to a value, not the value itself, and by the time the setTimeout is executed, your for loop has completed. This means that i would be 100 by the time function_opacity is called, making it look like your transition is not working.

Try changing the following code in changeImage and let me know how it goes.

```
//Setting opacity
if (done && fading_image.style.opacity != '1') {
done = false;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                    function_opacity(this, "in");
            }.bind(i), i*5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a problem with your setTimeout implementation.  The first argument to setTimeout must be a function reference, as opposed to a function invocation. You are using this concept properly in your setInterval. The visible difference is that you have no '()' after changeImage.

This raises another issue you will need resolved as you are passing arguments to your function_opacity invocation within the setTimeout. Try wrapping your function_opacity function invocation in an anonymous function